# How can a USB device tell if it is connected to a port?

Tags: connection, usb, detection, micropython

I have searched for an answer to this on Stack Overflow without success.

I have a small device running software written in MicroPython.  Normally, it is simply plugged into a power source via a USB cable, but I want it to be able to detect if it is plugged into a 'live' USB port on a PC, so that I can then interact with it.

There are lots of articles about how a PC can detect what is connected to its USB ports, and a number of articles related to Android devices connected to PCs, but I can find nothing that helps in this instance.

I am sure it can be done because I have a dashcam that works normally when simply plugged into power, but acts as a data source automatically when plugged into a live USB port.

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR (Raspberry Pico solution):

```
isUSBconnected = bool(machine.mem32[0x50110000 + 0x50] & (1<<16))
```

### Explanation

I ran in to this problem myself, also on a Rasberry Pico. It is possible to solve with Micropython. I could not find a ready-made function for this, so I used raw memory access to read the status register.

In the [RP2040 datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/rp2040-datasheet.pdf), we find that the USB device connectivity status is bit 16 of the `SIE_STATUS` register.

From section 4.1.4:

> The USB registers start at a base address of 0x50110000 (defined as USBCTRL_REGS_BASE in SDK).

In the following table, we find that the SIE status register is at offset 0x50.

So to find out if the device is connected, read the 32-bit register with [`machine.mem32`](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.html#memory-access), mask out bit 16 and cast the result to a boolean.

Comment: That's a very interesting (and very correct!) way of solving the problem!  As I mentioned, I have got round it, rather inelegantly, by monitoring the voltage on D+ which is different if the device is connected to a USB source.  However, this should be much more reliable, so I will certainly have a look.  Thank you!

Comment: What does "SIE" stand for?

Comment: @ComanderKai77 "SIE" stands for "Serial Interface Engine".

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pyboard, and it has the standard USB VCP (virtual COM port) function enabled, then according to [this answer](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11678&p=63614) on the old MicroPython forum you should be able to use

`pyb.USB_VCP().isconnected()`

If your device isn't an actual pyboard then I guess it depends what firmware it uses and whether the microcontroller supports similar functionality - you could ask at MicroPython's [GitHub Discussions](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/discussions) which has replaced the forum.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Unfortunately I am using a RasPi Pico.  However, I have managed to solve the problem (in a rather ugly fashion!) by linking the TP2 pad (USB D+ I think) to an ADC pin.  

If the Pico is plugged into a simple power source, D+ (and D-) are at around 2.5 volts.  When plugged into a USB port, D+ falls to zero.  I can detect the voltage on here and make the program respond accordingly.  

It's not 100% but it seems to work!